# Window Jupyter Notebook process sometimes stuck and need to press any key in the terminal to activate it again

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I start jupyter notebook by typing  `jupyter notebook`in anaconda prompt.

However when sometime we are executing the task, such as executing long-running cell,

sometime the process will stop and seems that the windows system didn't assign this jupyter process to continue,

I have to manually press any key in the anaconda prompt to activate it again.

Any idea on the reason why?

### conda version

```
packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3:
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda                  2020.02                  py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0
```

### window version

window 10 Pro

Comment: What OS? On windows, if Quick Edit is enabled for the window, clicking on the window can freeze it (and prevent new output being added) until a key is pressed.

Comment: This is a Windows problem, not Jupyter problem. https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/34

Comment: I don't think the above two comments are giving useful information,       this is nothing related to quickedit.   Quickedit only solve the situation that the terminal block output when you are doing some mouse operation.        The question here is the jupyter process has to be wake up by some mouse operation, and we want to find some way to keep this process running all the time  instead of need to be wake up.